# Class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments, but all parameters in constructor are optional

Tags: c#

I have a class which has a constructor, but has parameters that are optional.

```
public class foo 
{
    public foo(string variable1 = "", string variable2 = "", int variable3 = 0)
    {
        // Code goes here...
    }
}
```

When I try to call the class, of simply calling `foo()`, I wouldn't get any errors from Intellisense, but when I would build the project, I would get this error inside of BuildVision:

> 'foo' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Is there a way of solving this? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is an class and method I am trying to call is this:

```
public class NotImplementedExcept : BaseExcept
    public NotImplementedExcept(
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) : base(className, $"Method {memberName} is not implemented", memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber)
    {
    }
}
```

This is a custom way of handling NotImplementedExceptions. This way we are able to log exceptions and handle them more specificly to our needs. The paramaters would be filled by the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`. This is why they are optional.

The `BaseExcept` class is an abstract class which would handle how exceptions are logged.

Comment: Try overriding?

Comment: With that class definition `var foo = new foo();` works fine for me...

Comment: You should just 'obj ref not set to an instance' when you try to create that obj though

Comment: Which Visual Studio version do you use? Optional arguments in C# are introduced in VS 2010.

Comment: Interesting, can't say I have ever tried that myself. If you don't win here and discovered a "feature" that needs resolution from Microsoft. Consider injecting your dependencies using a configuration object and initialise the values within that object.

Comment: @Han I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: @Chris you are right. the problem is not reproducible

Comment: This is a non-repro, but the actual root cause is probably that you simplified your example too much. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. You're probably using inheritance; see duplicate.

Comment: @CodeCaster How is that a duplicate? OP hasn't provided any code besides c-tor and we don't know whether the issue is with `new()` or not. It's rather a 'not clear' question.

Comment: @MongZhu You are correct. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and 2012 but does not seems to be reproducing

Comment: I have added more information and a example to the post.

Comment: @Vlad yeah the title doesn't match, but the explanation in the duplicate explains the problem: optional parameters aren't really optional, so the OP _doesn't_ have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, I can't argue with that, though in my understanding that's not an exact duplicate because it requires OP to visit the answer and understand the connection between his issue and the described one. We can argue that understanding this connection is easy, but it really depends on one's experience. Apart from that, I seem to be not the only one who's against marking it as a duplicate until we're totally sure.

Comment: @Vlad I really don't want to keep discussing duplicates like this. Feel free to post an answer stating exactly what's explained in the now not-duplicate-anymore.

Comment: @Sam again, read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Your two code blocks have no relation whatsoever.

Comment: @SamBunting
Your code isn't related at all. Please provide the classes you use in your example and not arbitrary `foo` classes.

Comment: @Vlad Stryapko The example I am getting you is actually the method I am trying to fix. I just worded it completely wrong.